# Read images starting with a specific words together in Python

Tags: python

I have many images to read. for example *300* images with the names of `a1.jpg`, `a2.jpg`, ..., `a100.jpg`, `b1.jpg`, ..., `b100.jpg`, `c1.jpg`, `c2.jpg`, ..., `c100.jpg`. I want to use `imread()` function in a loop to find just those images starting with `a`.

I am using this command:

```
for i in train:
    im = misc.imread("/.../%s*.jpg" % i)
```

which *** mentions the rest of names starting with *a*. I do not know how to write this?

Comment: I want to move over the _train_ list by _i_. I mean using `%s` is important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `imread` itself.

Given that you already have the list of file names, you have several options:

1. Use `filter` to end up with only the filenames you want:

   ```
   relevant_files = filter(lambda name: name.startswith('a'), list_of_files)
   for file_name in relevant_files:
       im = misc.imread(file_name)
   ```
2. Use list comprehension:

   ```
   relevant_files = [file_name for file_name in list_of_files if file_name.startswith('a')]
   for file_name in relevant_files:
       im = misc.imread(file_name)
   ```
3. Use a simple `if` before reading the image:

   ```
   for i in train:
       if i.startswith('a'):
            im = misc.imread(i)
   ```
4. Do `import glob` and use it as shown by @LaurentLAPORTE in the comment.

Comment: You can also use `glob.glob` function: `relevant_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "a*.jpg"))`.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Of course, just wasn't sure of the top of my head if `glob` was cross-platform

Comment: The _train_ list is the name of all images. I want to move over the list by _i_. Hence, _i_ would be the start of the name wanted.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, how we can use `relevant_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "a*.jpg"))' in imread command?

Comment: @AmnKh Again, this has nothing to do with `imread`. `imread` simply reads the image that you provide it. What ever this file is, is up to you. You need to iterate over the `relevant_files` list and open each file with `imread` just like you did in your example.

Comment: I used what @LaurentLAPORTE recommend like the below:
`relevant_files=glob.glob(os.path.join("/.../", "%s*.png" %i)) and 
`for i in relevant_files:
    im=misc.imread(i)`

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting place to use `iterools.groupby`

```
>>> x = ['a1.jpg', 'a2.jpg', 'b1.jpg', 'b2.jpg']
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(x, lambda t:t[0])
>>> for key,l in groups:
...   print (key)
...   for j in l:
...     print ("  ",j)
... 
a
('  ', 'a1.jpg')
('  ', 'a2.jpg')
b
('  ', 'b1.jpg')
('  ', 'b2.jpg')
```

The list of files can be generated using `glob.glob` or `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & Dirty:

```
charToRead = 'a'
for i in range(100):
    s = charToRead + str(i+1) + '.jpg'
    print(s)
    im=misc.imread(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list out all the images in a list first and loop over them.
Suppose ,

```
a = ['a1.jpg', 'a2.jpg', 'a100.jpg','b10.jpg','c100.jpg']
matching = [s for s in a if s.startswith('a')]
```

The matching will be a list of all images having name started with 'a' character.

Comment: The _train_ list is the name of all images. I want to move over the list by _i_. Hence, _i_ would be the start of the name wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If all your image are in the same repertory, you can browse all the file name in this repertory, check if it start by a, if yes then display it imread. It would do soemthing like :

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".jpg") and file.startwith("a"):
         im=misc.imread(file)
```

It should work. I hope it does help.